# Density of Dolean exponentials in L2  and Wiener Measure 

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus, measure-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Assume that W is the classical Wiener space C([0,1],R) note $\mu$ the Wiener measure, and denote by $\mu_s$ the image of $\mu$ under the maping $T: W ->W$ such that$ T(w)= \sqrt(s) w$ . Denote by $W_t$ the coordinate functionnal  defined by $W_t(w)=w_t$, denote by $F_t$ the borel sigma field of $W_t$,and define the stochastic intégral as usual.It is a classical result that the linear span of the set $e^{\int u_v dW_t -\int \frac{u^2}{2} dt}$, u in $L^2[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2(\mu)$.  My question is :

Is that true that the linear span f the set  $e^{\int \frac{u_v}{s} dW_t -\int \frac{u^2}{2s}dt}$ , u in $L^2[0,1]$ , is dense in $L^2(\mu_s)$ ???

I want to draw your attention on the fact that the expecation of $e^{\int \frac{u_v}{s} dW_t -\int \frac{u^2}{2s}dt}$ is 1 under $\mu_s$, but not those of $e^{\int \frac{u_v}{s} dW_t -\int \frac{u^2}{2s^2}dt}$, moreover $e^{\int \frac{u_v}{s} dW_t -\int \frac{u^2}{2s}dt}$  is a weight that enables to use the Cameron -Martin theorem (or even the Girsanov theorem) on the space $(W,F,\mu_s)$.

Comment: Syd, I think you have an interesting question in there, but your grammar and syntax are very hard to parse.  Could you please edit your question and make it more clear?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it's done .